# RedirectionToAction with Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

In MVC Core you can use:

```
RedirectionToAction(Action, Controller, model)
```

The model properties are then converted to `QueryString` parameters.

However, if one of the properties of the model is a `List` then that particular property is not correctly added to the `QueryString`.

For example if a property is a `List` of `Shirt` objects and has the name `Shirts`, then the query parameter is added as:

```
Shirts=NameSpace.Models.Shirt
```

as opposed to:

```
Shirts[0].Color="red"&Shirts[1].color="blue"
```

Does anyone know how to correctly serialize this so that the `QueryString` gets created correctly?

Comment: I'd avoid using lists in parameters, but if you have to, you can serialize the model manually. It's easy.

Comment: @Racil Hilan Is it possible to provide some code so that we can mark it as answer?

Comment: Don't send the model in query string instead try to use TempData, ViewData or Session and then redirect to action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending complex models in `RedirectionToAction()` indicates a design flaw. I cannot think of any good reason for this. Complex models should be coming to your actions from form submits (or Ajax submits) or similar user actions, not from your own code of other actions. Redirects should be either parameter-less or with very few simple parameters. That's probably why the `RedirectionToAction()` is not bothered with serializing your list.

Having said that, if you insist on doing it that way, nothing stops you from doing the serialization by yourself. It's fairly simple.

First, no double quotes around the values in the query string.

Second, for simple array properties, the syntax `property[0]=value&property[1]=value` will work. Also for object propertied, the dot notation `property.property=value` will work too. But for a list of objects property like in your question, you can try using the dot notation `Shirts[0].Color=red` like you mentioned. I haven't tried it myself to see if the controller can bind to it successfully. I will continue this answer with the assumption that it can, because your question is about the serialization.

Let's say the `Shirt` class has also an integer `Size` property. And let's say your model is an order with an integer `Id` and a decimal `Total` properties, in additions to the list `Shirts` property. You can serialize your model like this:

```
var qs = $"?Id={model.Id}"
        + "&Total={model.Total}";

for(var i = 0; i < model.Shirts.Count(); i++) {
  var s = model.Shirts[i];
  qs += $"&Shirts[{i}].Size={s.Size}"
       + "&Shirts[{i}].Color={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(s.Model)}";
}
```

I didn't handle the case if `Shirts` can be `null`, you can do so if required.

Now, you pass the query string to `Redirect()`. You can use `Url.Action()` to create the URL itself (i.e. before the query string):

```
Redirect(Url.Action(Action, Controller, model) + qs);
```